# How can I install wine and vncserver as well as update software on Red Hat with no subscription?

Tags: rhel, yum, vnc

I would like to update and install some software on a Red Hat machine but have no subscription and don't plan on getting one. To get Wine I'm following [this tutorial](http://tecadmin.net/steps-install-wine-centos-rhel-fedora-systems/).

After doing

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

I get:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
There is no installed groups file.
Maybe run: yum groups mark convert (see man yum)
Warning: group Development Tools does not exist.
Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

Comment: I decided to download a CentOS iso (6.8 in my case) and just replace red hat altogether. Was able to install packages as needed from centos repos'

Answer (score 1):

If you want RHEL without paying, install CentOS. If you want RHEL, pay for subscription, the developer subscription is $99.

Edit: actually, like dominix says, the developer subscription is free now, since March 2016.

Answer (score 1):

you can subscribe for free to "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Suite" and then access to the update. But in your case you just need to go with CentOS which is completely compatible.