# Red Hat 6.9 Desktop yum groupinstall Developer Tools not found?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum, development, compiler

I searched everywhere on the web for a few days, and I am still stuck...

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Desktop 6.9 in a virtual machine. I am using an older version because I am experimenting with legacy grub 1. I am about to compile a Linux kernel too as well. But, I need to install the yum group  package called 'Developer Tools' first.

When I run:

```
# yum groupinstall 'Developer Tools'
```

I then get an error message stating that the group does not exist:

```
Warning: Group Development Tools does not exist.
```

I tried enabling some repos, such as rhel-client-dts-6-rhb-rpms, to no avail.
I even subscribed to the $99 developer Red Hat subscription.

---

### EDIT

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

returns:

```
Warning: Group Development Tools does not exist.
Error: No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

---

```
yum groupinstall development
```

returns:

```
Warning: Group development does not exist.
Error: No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

---

```
yum grouplist
```

returns:

```
Available Groups:
Backup Client
Client management tools
Console internet tools
Graphics Creation Tools
Guest Agents
KDE Desktop
Mainframe Access
Messaging Client Support
Remote Desktop Clients
Ruby Support
Smart card support
TeX support
Technical Writing
Virtualization
Virtualization Client
Virtualization Platform
Virtualization Tools
```

---

```
yum groupinfo -v 'Development tools'
```

returns:

```
Warning: Group Development tools does not exist.
```

---

I don't know why this is not working?

---

### EDIT

I am not sure what repository I need to enable, or even if I need to get another subscription. I have the Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Suite ($99) and the Red Hat Enterprise Linux Desktop/Workstation ($49).

This command ...:

```
subscription-manager repos —list
```

... gives this output:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
    Available Repositories in /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo
+----------------------------------------------------------+
Repo ID:   rhel-6-client-rhev-agent-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization Agents for RHEL 6 Client (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhev-agent/3/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-2.3-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 2.3 /(RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/2.3/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-client-dts-6-rhb-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Developer Toolset RHB RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Client
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/rhb/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/devtoolset/os
Enabled:   1

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6-beta-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6 Beta (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-rhn-tools-rpms
Repo Name: RHN Tools for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhn-tools/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6-puppet-upgrade-beta-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6 Beta - Puppet Upgrade (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6-puppet-upgrade/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-rhn-tools-debug-rpms
Repo Name: RHN Tools for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhn-tools/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-extras-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Extras (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/extras/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-supplementary-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Supplementary (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/supplementary/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-2.2-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 2.2 /(RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/2.2/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-optional-beta-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Optional Beta (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/optional/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-supplementary-debuginfo
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Supplementary (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/supplementary/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.2-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.2 /(RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.2/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-thirdparty-oracle-java-beta-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Oracle Java Beta (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/oracle-java/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6.1-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.1 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6.1/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6.3-puppet4-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.3 - Puppet 4 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6.3-puppet4/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-thirdparty-oracle-java-beta-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Oracle Java Beta (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/oracle-java/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.2-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.2 /(Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.2/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-rh-common-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - RH Common (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rh-common/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-rhn-tools-beta-debug-rpms
Repo Name: RHN Tools for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop Beta (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhn-tools/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-supplementary-beta-debuginfo
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Supplementary Beta (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/supplementary/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-rhn-tools-source-rpms
Repo Name: RHN Tools for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhn-tools/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-client-rhev-agent-beta-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization Agents for RHEL 6 Client Beta (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhev-agent/3/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6-beta-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6 Beta (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.0-beta-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.0 Beta /(Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/atomic/7/$basearch/cdk/3.0/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-2.4-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 2.4 /(Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/2.4/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-client-rhv-4-agent-beta-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Virtualization 4 Agents for RHEL 6 Client Beta (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhv-agent/4/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-client-rhev-agent-beta-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization Agents for RHEL 6 Client Beta (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhev-agent/3/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-insights-3-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Insights 3 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/insights/3/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.1-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.1 /(RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.1/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-rh-common-beta-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - RH Common Beta (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/rh-common/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.0-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.0 /(RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.0/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6-puppet-upgrade-beta-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6 Beta - Puppet Upgrade (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6-puppet-upgrade/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-2.3-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 2.3 /(Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/2.3/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6.3-puppet4-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.3 - Puppet 4 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6.3-puppet4/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.1-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.1 /(Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.1/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-fastrack-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Fastrack (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/fastrack/rhel/client/6/$basearch/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-extras-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Extras (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/extras/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-optional-beta-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Optional Beta (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/optional/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6.2-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.2 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6.2/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-thirdparty-oracle-java-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Oracle Java (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/oracle-java/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-host-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6.2-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.2 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6.2/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-host-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-2.4-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 2.4 /(RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/2.4/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-client-rhv-4-agent-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Virtualization 4 Agents for RHEL 6 Client (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhv-agent/4/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-extras-debuginfo
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Extras (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/extras/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-host-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-client-rhev-agent-beta-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization Agents for RHEL 6 Client Beta (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhev-agent/3/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-host-beta-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host Beta (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/atomic/7/$basearch/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-host-beta-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host Beta (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/atomic/7/$basearch/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-rh-common-beta-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - RH Common Beta (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/rh-common/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-beta-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop Beta (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6.3-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.3 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6.3/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-rh-common-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - RH Common (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rh-common/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-optional-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Optional (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/optional/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.2-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.2 /(Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.2/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-client-rhv-4-agent-beta-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Virtualization 4 Agents for RHEL 6 Client Beta (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhv-agent/4/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-beta-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop Beta (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-2.4-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 2.4 /(Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/2.4/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6-puppet-upgrade-beta-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6 Beta - Puppet Upgrade (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6-puppet-upgrade/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-client-rhev-agent-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization Agents for RHEL 6 Client (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhev-agent/3/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-client-dts-6-rhb-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Developer Toolset RHB Debug RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Client
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/rhb/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/devtoolset/debug
Enabled:   1

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.4-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.4 /(Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.4/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6.3-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.3 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6.3/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6.1-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.1 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6.1/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6.1-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.1 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6.1/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.4-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.4 /(Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.4/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.3-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.3 /(Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.3/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-rhn-tools-beta-rpms
Repo Name: RHN Tools for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop Beta (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhn-tools/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6.2-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.2 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6.2/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.0-beta-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.0 Beta /(Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/atomic/7/$basearch/cdk/3.0/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.1-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.1 /(Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.1/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-beta-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop Beta (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-client-rhev-agent-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization Agents for RHEL 6 Client (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhev-agent/3/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6.3-puppet4-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.3 - Puppet 4 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6.3-puppet4/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-rh-common-beta-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - RH Common Beta (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/rh-common/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-client-dts-6-rhb-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Developer Toolset RHB Source RPMs for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Client
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/rhb/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/devtoolset/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   1

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-optional-beta-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Optional Beta (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/optional/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-supplementary-beta-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Supplementary Beta (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/supplementary/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-optional-fastrack-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Optional Fastrack (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/fastrack/rhel/client/6/$basearch/optional/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-supplementary-beta-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Supplementary Beta (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/supplementary/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.3-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.3 /(RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.3/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-insights-3-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Insights 3 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/insights/3/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-thirdparty-oracle-java-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Oracle Java (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/oracle-java/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-supplementary-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Supplementary (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/supplementary/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-fastrack-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Fastrack (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/fastrack/rhel/client/6/$basearch/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-host-beta-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host Beta (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/atomic/7/$basearch/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-rhn-tools-beta-source-rpms
Repo Name: RHN Tools for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop Beta (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhn-tools/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/os
Enabled:   1

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.3-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.3 /(Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.3/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.0-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.0 /(Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.0/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-optional-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Optional (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/optional/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-insights-3-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Insights 3 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/insights/3/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.4-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.4 /(RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.4/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-rh-common-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - RH Common (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rh-common/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-client-rhv-4-agent-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Virtualization 4 Agents for RHEL 6 Client (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhv-agent/4/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-2.2-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 2.2 /(Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/2.2/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-optional-fastrack-source-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Optional Fastrack (Source RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/fastrack/rhel/client/6/$basearch/optional/source/SRPMS
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6-beta-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6 Beta (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/beta/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-atomic-7-cdk-3.0-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Container Development Kit 3.0 /(Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/atomic/7/7Server/$basearch/cdk/3.0/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-fastrack-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Fastrack (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/fastrack/rhel/client/6/$basearch/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-satellite-tools-6.3-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.3 (for RHEL 6 Desktop) (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/6Client/$basearch/sat-tools/6.3/debug
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-desktop-optional-fastrack-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Desktop - Optional Fastrack (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/fastrack/rhel/client/6/$basearch/optional/os
Enabled:   0

Repo ID:   rhel-6-client-rhv-4-agent-debug-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Virtualization 4 Agents for RHEL 6 Client (Debug RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/client/6/$releasever/$basearch/rhv-agent/4/debug
Enabled:   0
```

Thanks everybody for your help!

---

I ended up solving this issue...
The problem is that I was using the $49 basic RHEL Desktop subscription, but I needed the $179 RHEL Workstation subscription. Red Hat just wanted more money :)

Comment: For Developer Tools:                                                                    
Warning: Group Developer Tools does not exist.
Error: No packages in any requested group available to install or update

Comment: For Development Tools: Warning: Group Development Tools does not exist. Error: No packages in any requested group available to install or update

Comment: I wonder if your subscription is not attached to the right repo. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/305106/117549 and check the output of `subscription-manager repos —list`

Comment: See here: https://developers.redhat.com/articles/using-gcc4-rhel-6-red-hat-developer-toolset-dts/

Comment: I will edit my question when I get home, sorry for the hassle.

Comment: I found the solution, you should label it as solved.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the group has a *name* of "Development Tools" and an *id* of "development", so you should use one of those two names with yum.

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

or

```
yum groupinstall development
```

To see a list of available groups, use:

```
yum grouplist
```

... among which you may see:

```
...
   Desktop Platform Development
   Development tools
   Dial-up Networking Support
...
```

You can get the id of a group using the `-v` flag:

```
yum groupinfo -v 'Development tools'
```

Results in (partial output):

```
...
Group: Development tools
 Group-Id: development
 Description: A basic development environment.
...
```